# iOS AWS SNS Create platform application fail with error "There was an error reading the selected certificate."

Tags: ios, certificate, amazon-sns

After downloading my certificate from the apple developer portal, I successfully create a p12 file but whenever I try to create a platform application on aws, enter the certificate password, I just keep getting the error below.

> There was an error reading the selected certificate. Verify the
> password and try again.

I have tried with short and no passwords but nothing seems to accept the password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work, by doing the following:

- Delete all old keys related to previous attempts in your Keychain > login (macos)
- Request a new certificate from Request Certificate from Authority. Make sure no keys are selected when you execute this function.
- I chose a single word in lowercase for Common name.
- Add certificate to Apple Developer Portal
- Download the CSR
- Double click on the CSR to import the keys into your Keychain.
- Your private key should have a dropdown with the certificate listed. My previous attempts did not have this. Export the p12.
- The p12 worked in AWS SNS when entering the password, the public and private keys were extracted from the p12.